# ruby / rails 3 ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, errno

When I run my application, there is sometimes this error appears

**ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED**

This is the log:

> [2011-06-05 18:17:21] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte.
>
> ```
>     C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:323:in `write'
>     C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:323:in`<<'
>     C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:323:in `_write_data'
>     C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:295:in `send_body_string'
>     C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:186:in `send_body'
>     C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:103:in `send_response'
>     C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:86:in `run'
>     C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
> ```

The most annoying is that this error happens randomly.

Despite extensive research I can not know the cause of the problem

So, does anyone have an idea of the problem?

Ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0.7, Windows 7 64 bits

Comment: I have the same problem. This is an error that happens randomly in a request. You see it appear in a request and vanishing after, only to return a couple of requests later.
It seems to me it is a problem with Webrick.

Comment: My Windows Webrick also collapses every a hundred requests or so --I hate developing for RoR on windows, the experience sucks